# Does OneLogin SCIM provisioning support OAuth Refresh tokens?

Tags: onelogin, scim

[The documentation](https://developers.onelogin.com/scim/create-app) (under "configure your SCIM test app") states that a bearer token is required.

Is this a never-expiring OAuth access token? Can OneLogin be configured to use a refresh token to obtain new refresh and access tokens?

Answer (score 1):

OneLogin doesn't currently support refreshing access tokens for SCIM (but we're working on it) - Just the standard bearer tokens available either directly or via an OAuth authentication flow.

Currently, we've only seen one application that has this requirement (out of many, many dozens of SCIM implementations) so it hasn't been a priority for us.

Comment: By using an OAuth authentication flow, does this mean that a provisioning event always requires or is triggered by an end-user action? Is it possible to store credentials and have provisioning run on a schedule or via system-generated events?

Comment: OneLogin does the latter.

And admin does the OAuth flow to authorize OneLogin to update users in the application and OneLogin saves the bearer token.

Afterwards, whenever a user gets updated in OL (or in a directory OL is connected to) it fires off an API call to the application to update the user.